# Navigation Menu Made New Toolbar Below Existing Toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, toolbar, navigationbar

I made a navigation menu, and after a few changes the app kept stopping. I tried a few things, and looked online for some solutions until I got it to work again. Now, the Navigation Menu is its own toolbar now and is below the old toolbar. I want the navigation menu's hamburger icon to be inside the existing toolbar, not its own thing. All help is very much appreciated! Thank You[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGVt5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending a specific theme in your app theme in your `values.xml`

Change the theme to a theme ending with `NoActionBar`

For example: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`